# Getting a particular substring

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like this

```
"Macro HarryAnd6767 exist Open Search Panel Star23 else Proceed with DavidAnd6768"
```

I want to retrieve `"HarryAnd6767"` and `"DavidAnd6768"` . Both `"HarryAnd6767"` and `"DavidAnd6768"` are dynamic which are getting changed at each code execution based on user inputs .

Please help in this .Thanks in advance .

Comment: do the words you want to retrieve always appear in the same position in the string?

Comment: But what is the pattern of the substring to search?

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Yes words appears at the same position always .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use split method to split a string using a separator. For example,

```
String myStr = "Macro HarryAnd6767 exist Open Search Panel Star23 else Proceed with DavidAnd6768"
String[] strTbl = myStr.Split(' ')
String Name1 = strTbl[1]
String Name2 = strTbl[10]
```

Comment: What will be the solution if myStr=""MacroHarryAnd6767existOpen SearchPanelStar23elseProceedwithDavidAnd6768""

Comment: Take a look at indexOf and substring methods.

Answer (score 2):

If the words are always the second and 11th word, you could use:

```
var split = inputString.Split(' ');
string first = split[1];
string second = split[10];
```

Note that you may want additional error checking (ie: make sure there are enough words in place in advance, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the words you want to retrieve always appear in the same position in the string (on a 0 based index: 1,10) you can do it like this:

```
string[] splitStrings=originalString.Split(' ');
string firstWord=splitStrings[1];
string secondWord=splitStrings[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what are you trying to find exacly, but if the pattern is the same, you can use regular expressions in the following way:

```
string str = "Macro HarryAnd6767 exist Open Search Panel Star23 else Proceed with DavidAnd6768";
string pattern = "Macro (.*) exist Open Search Panel Star23 else Proceed with (.*)";
var match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    string first = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string second = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```